# Can you setup listener socket on localhost with iOS?

Tags: ios, sockets

I'm trying to setup a listenerSocket on **localhost** using `GCDAsyncSocket` for iOS device.

In the `socketDidDisconnect` delegate I either get error *Code=49* for trying with port 0 (which I'm hoping would find the first available free port).
Or if I use a port no then I get error *Code=61* for trying to connect with `localhost`.

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender {
    asyncSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    NSError *err = nil;
    if(![asyncSocket connectToHost:@"localhost" onPort:0 error:&err])
    {
        NSLog(@"Connect Error: %@", err);
    }
}

#pragma mark – delegate

-(void)socketDidDisconnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock withError:(NSError *)err
{
    NSLog(@"socketDidDisconnect");
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"Socket Error: %@", err);
        // Error in connect function:
        // NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=49 "Can't assign requested address" - onPort:0
        // NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "Connection refused" - connectToHost:@"localhost"
    }
}
```

Comment: You certainly can't use port 0. Ports below 1024 are reserved for "privileged" processes on Unix operating systems (such as OS X and iOS) so I would try 1025 or higher but more importantly this code tries to make a connection to a socket, it does not set up a listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connectToHost` will act as the client-side of the connection.  You want to read the *Writing a server* section of the [help page](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/wiki/Intro_GCDAsyncSocket):

```
listenSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![listenSocket acceptOnPort:port error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"I goofed: %@", error);
}

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sender didAcceptNewSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)newSocket
{
    // The "sender" parameter is the listenSocket we created.
    // The "newSocket" is a new instance of GCDAsyncSocket.
    // It represents the accepted incoming client connection.

    // Do server stuff with newSocket...
}
```

However you need to know the port to use (if you let the system decide what port to use then how is a client supposed to know how to connect to the server?).  Also the port will almost certainly need to be `> 1024` (out of the reserved port range).  However I haven't ever tried to create a Server on iOS.